# Should EMV data fields be encrypted?

Tags: pci-dss, emv

Are there any EMV data fields considered to be sensitive data according to the PCI DSS standard?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this website article (https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/will-emv-make-you-pci-compliant/) it looks like that **yes, the data, specifically the PAN needs to be encrypted in accordance with PCI.**

Comment: Indeed, tags 5A and 57 are some of the culprits